# If Else Statement in Linear Program, making it Mixed Integer Program

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

How to write the following if-else condition in Linear Programming or in Mixed Integer Program?

If a <= b then c = a

else ( a > b) then c = b

a, b, c are all variables. Is it possible to rewrite this without doing it nonlinear?

a,b,c >0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to enforce $c=\min(a,b)$.  If $c$ naturally (because of the objective or otherwise) satisfies $c\ge\min(a,b)$, it suffices to enforce $c\le\min(a,b)$:
\begin{align}
c&\le a \\
c&\le b
\end{align}

Otherwise, see
https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/how-to-linearize-min-function-as-a-constraint

Comment: Sorry for late reply, c did not naturally satisfy >= min but otherwise link worked great. Thank you, didnt know that link, appreciate